# SQL - SUM on similar values based on two conditions

Tags: sql

I am stuck trying to write this SQL and receiving this error message

> ODBC::Error: 37000 (1003) SQL compilation error: syntax error line 8
> at position 8 unexpected 'GROUP'.: Select CASE WHEN forgiven = 0 THEN
> 6 - SUM(attendance_points) END as total_attendance_p

Goal: Get the sum attendance_points for the same driver_id's if forgiven = 0 and attendance_points in the last 90 days to the current date.

```
driver_id   attendance_points  forgiven    date
8087956           6                0     2020-02-12
8087956           1                0     2020-02-12
1160725           2                0     2020-02-01
1160725           6                0     2020-02-12
7922706           4                1     2020-02-13
```

```
Select
    CASE WHEN forgiven = 0 THEN 6 - SUM(attendance_points) END as total_attendance_points,
    driver_id,
    date

    FROM attendance_events
    WHERE date < DATEADD("day", -90, current_date());

    GROUP BY 2
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your query uses non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: So, the query result is a list with one row per driver and three columns: 1. the driver ID, 2. the attendance total for forgiven = 0 regardless of the date, 3. the attendence total in the last 90 days regardless of the forgiven status. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation

```
Select driver_id,date,
    sum(CASE WHEN forgiven = 0 THEN 6 - attendance_points END ) as total_attendance_points
    FROM attendance_events
    WHERE date < DATEADD("day", -90, current_date())
    group BY driver_id,date
```

Answer (score 0):

use from below query

```
select driver_id,sum(attendance_points) from attendance_events where forgiven=0 and date >= DATEADD("day", -90, GETDATE()) group by driver_id
```

you can see result in photo
[image]